# I want to get the maximum occurred number from the mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I got the maximum occurred value from each column. But I need from the entire table. Can someone guide me with this? Here in this table it should be 11.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEAaX.png)

Comment: Do you mean the most common, not the maximum (highest) ?

Comment: If you take a look at that table 11 is occurred for 7 times. 7 times is the max. So I need that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of count and group by, with a limit:

```
SELECT columnname, COUNT(columnname) AS count 
  FROM table
  GROUP BY columnname
  ORDER BY COUNT(columnname) DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: I have used the exact query. This gave me the maximum occurred number of one column. But I want it from all columns. Isn't there any way to do that? Otherwise I have to use an array to retrieve the maximum again from the max occurred numbers. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: You will need to loop over each column and run that query... or run it as a lot of subqueries